# Android Java - Preventing GC_FOR_ALLOC with large quantity of bitmaps

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I would like to know if there are any optimizations that could be used to improve the speed when using a large quantity of bitmaps drawn on a screen.

I use a canvas which I load all my resources at the initialization and use createBitmap when I need to update the bitmap. I use ~10-15kb files with my Galaxy Note 3 and notice a lag (xxhdpi) when I reach around 20 bitmaps which gets nearly unusable around 35+.

I am using createbitmap constantly because the bitmaps use frame animation and matrix to rotate.

So far the only thing i've tried that i've noticed a difference is inBitmap which gives about 5-10% increase in the GC_FOR_ALLOC freed.

Anyone care to chime in on a good answer for what is better? I've heard flash AIR is a good choice to go with using cacheAsBitmapMatrix, but I would like a different option (just personal pref).

EDIT:

(rectf bounds = bitmap bounds)

```
matrix.setRotate(rotation, rectf.centerX(), rectf.centerY());
ship1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(ship1, 0, 0, ship1.getWidth(), ship1.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

I think I understand my problem, I should be calling

```
canvas.drawBitmap(ship1, matrix, paint);
```

But in my onDraw method I am using

```
canvas.drawBitmap(ship1, srcRectf, dstRectf, paint); //srcRectf = null
```

I use dstRectf to move my bitmap around, but I suppose this can be replaced with setTranslate.  I'll try it out, thanks Mehmet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitmap stores the pixel data in the native heap*, not in the java heap, and takes care of managing it by itself. That would mean GC shouldn't give you any serious headaches.

The problem is probably constantly using `createBitmap()`, which is usually a really costly operation. This will make a disk IO call at worst, or a relatively big memory allocation at best. You would like to use it as little as possible, i.e. only when initially reading them from the disk.

Instead I advise you to use a `Matrix` in conjunction with a `Canvas`. Just change your `Matrix` and with each step repaint your `Bitmap`s  with it.

EDIT:

*Only correct for Android 2.3.3 <-> Android 3.0

Comment: Could you care to explain any further? I do rotate a matrix, and then createBitmap with the matrix.  What is repainting?  I edited at the bottom to show some code that I use

Comment: I think I understand, I am using a custom draw view so I can use canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);  But how can I call this while I also call canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRectf, dstRectf, paint);?

Comment: Exactly, I believe matrix can scale and trim as well. Take a look at it because I am not very familiar with the android's matrix.

Comment: You are welcome, I didn't get your question. What do you mean by instances or new resource? If new resource means you haven't loaded it in memory in some way, yes you should call `createBitmap`.

Comment: Sorry for deleting it, I should think before I hit enter :P  - In my code I initiate each bitmaps with createBitmap once, and throw them in an array so I can reuse them.  Having your guidance right here and now threw me into a 'i need to ask as much as i can now' mode. Haha!